# Call function in fields in model yii2

Tags: yii2

I am new to yii2 and how to call a function fields?

```
public function fields{
    'id',
    'name'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i have no ideas what you are trying to accomplish. can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.

```
public function fields() {
 'id',
'name',
'city'
}

 public function getCity(){
  return "City";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean function in fields?
just do the following:

```
public function fields() {
   'id',
   'name',
   'address'
}

public function getAddress(){
    return "Newyork City";
}
```

It's a simplest way to call any function in fields...Hope that would help